# Does Jackson TypeReference work when extended?

Tags: java, json, jackson

In the following snippet, you can see that the type information is not erased, but the mapper doesn't get the type information. My guess is that Jackson doesn't allow this, right? If I pass a `TypeReference` directly, it is deserialized properly.

```
public class AgentReq<T> extends TypeReference<AgentResponse<T>> {...}

mapper.readValue(reader, new AgentReq<Map<String, Set<Whatever>>>());
```

It also doesn't work if I do this:

```
public class AgentReq<T> {

    public TypeReference<AgentResponse<T>> getTypeRef() {
        return new TypeReference<AgentResponse<T>>() {};
    }
}

mapper.readValue(reader, new AgentReq<Map<String, Set<Whatever>>>()).getTypeRef();
```

I'm using version 2.1.5.

EDIT: For future reference, do not underestimate the `TypeReference` constructor when resolving problems. There you can see directly whether it was able to retrieve type information. By the way, the answer is: NO, you can't extend `TypeReference` and expect it to work. You can't even override its `getType()` method and supply it with type information resolved from your class, because all you can get is `getClass().getGenericSuperClass()`. You can't do `getClass().getGenericClass()`.

Comment: Can you provide a class that would use that `TypeReference`? A small SSCCE?

Comment: It's 1:35 AM, I have to go to sleep Sotirios... I'll take a look at it tomorrow morning again.

Comment: NP, I'll try it when I go home too.

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51767347/5515060

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to understand how a `TypeReference` works. For that we go into the source code

```
protected TypeReference()
{
    Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
    }
    ...
    _type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

The `Class#getGenericSuperclass()` javadoc states

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
>   (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the Type object returned
>   must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source
>   code.

In other words, if we could do `new TypeReference()` (we can't, it's abstract), it would return the `Class` instance for the class `Object`. However, with anonymous classes (which extend from the type)

```
new TypeReference<String>(){}
```

the direct superclass of the instance created is the parameterized type `TypeReference` and according to the javadoc we should get a `Type` instance that *accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code*:

```
TypeReference<String>
```

from which you can then get the parameterized type with `getActualTypeArguments()[0])`, returning `String`.

Let's take an example to visualize using anonymous class and using a sub-class

```
public class Subclass<T> extends TypeReference<AgentResponse<T>>{
    public Subclass() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

Running

```
new Subclass<String>();
```

prints

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<Test.AgentResponse<T>>
Test.AgentResponse<T>
```

which fits the javadoc rules. `Test.AgentResponse<T>` is the actual parameterized type in the source code. Now, if instead, we had

```
new Subclass<String>(){}; // anonymous inner class
```

we get the result

```
Test.Subclass<java.lang.String>
class java.lang.String
```

which also fits the bill. The inner class now extends directly from `Subclass` which is parameterized with the argument `String` in the source code.

You will notice that, with the `Subclass` anonymous inner class, we've lost information about the `AgentResponse` generic type. This is unavoidable.

---

Note that

```
reader = new StringReader("{\"element\":{\"map-element\":[{\"name\":\"soto\", \"value\": 123}]}}");
obj = mapper.readValue(reader, new AgentReq<Map<String, Set<Whatever>>>());
```

will compile and run, but the type `AgentReq<Map<String, Set<Whatever>>>` will have been lost. Jackson will use default type to serializes the JSON. The `element` will be deserialized as an `AgentResponse`, while `map-element` will be deserialized as a `Map` and the JSON array as an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I underestimated the TypeReference constructor where, as you described, all the important stuff happens and one can see that unless you directly instantiate the TypeReference abstract class as an anonymous one, it doesn't have a chance to resolve the type information. Thank you