# Jackson TypeReference using inner class

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

Having problem with casting in Java recently I have used TypeReference object of Jackson. The situation looked liked this:

```
List<myObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<myObject>();

listOfObjects = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), new ArrayList.class);
```

was throwing an exception that LinkedHashMap could not be cast into myObject. I understand now what was wrong with it after some helpful person on SO told me to use TypeReference. I replace second line with:

```
listOfObjects = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<List<myObject>>(){});
```

and there is just one thing that I cannot (still...) understand here: what is the inner class for here (`{}`)? I obviously don't know all use cases of inner classes so I could use a bit of explanation here. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Jackson TypeReference work when extended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283606/does-jackson-typereference-work-when-extended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a thing called type erasure. That means, once compiled, your

```
List<myObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<myObject>();
```

becomes

```
List listOfObjects = new ArrayList();
```

Therefore, once running your program Jackson cannot tell that you are expecting back a List of `myObject`s. Instead it returns a list of `LinkedHashMap`s. By creating an inner class extending `TypeReference` you are forcing Java to retain the fact that you are expecting a list of type `myObject`.

See here for the explanation from the Authors: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. I have found what you linked for a couple of minutes ago, but after posting the question, therefore even though I already knew the answer you're effort will be rewarded. And I really should start trying harder before posting questions, because it's not the first time :(  Thanks!

Comment: @fge I just took the first that came up in Google. Fixed that. Didn't make much of a difference.