# Jackson deserialize an object that implements an interface and ignore the interface properties

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have an annotated class that implements an interface with a *read-only* property named `.id()` that is generic so I can pull different types of *ids* in other parts of the program.

This entire interface should be ignored by Jackson. But instead I get the following error message:

> `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`:
>   `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException`: Cannot
>   construct instance of `my.company.Identifiable` (no Creators,
>   like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be
>   mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain
>   additional type information  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column:
>   -1] (through reference chain: `java.util.HashSet[0]`)

I have tried all the solutions found here when searching for that exception as well as the entire first two pages from Google. None of them address the exact problem I am having and I have been unable to interpalate a solution for my specific problem from any of them, short of a `CustomDeserializer` which I would rather not have to write.

I tried using `JsonTypeInfo` but I have never had to use that annotation before and can not figure out what I am supposed to do with it. The solutions that uses are slightly different from mine, where they actually **want** the interface property instead of ignoring it.

In some classes there is no actual `id` member variable, it is just a `method` to return something that is considered the `id` for another part of the program. `ID<String>` in some cases and `ID<Integer>` in others.

I have tried annotating with `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` as well as the `@JsonIgnore` and the `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})` none of them change the exception. I also tried all the `mode` settings in `@JsonCreator`, none worked.

The interface is defined as:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"id"})
public interface Identifiable<T>
{
    @JsonIgnore
    public T id();
}
```

An example class is defined as:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User implements Identifiable<ID<String>>
{
    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("LoginName") final String loginName,
                @JsonProperty("Title") final String name,
                @JsonProperty("Email") final String email)
/* lots of irrelevant code redacted */

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public ID<String> id()
    {
        return new ID.from(this.name);
    }
}
```

This what the binding code looks like:

```
final HttpResponse response = req.execute();
final JsonNode root = this.om.readTree(response.getContent());
final JsonNode results = root.get("d").get("results");
final Set<V> values = this.om.readValue(this.om.treeAsTokens(results), 
                                        new TypeReference<Set<V>>() {});
```

Where `V` is `User` in this case and `results` is an `Array`.

Deserialization of this and a couple other classes worked fine before I added the `Identifiable<T>` interface, they they all broke with this same exception.

This is not an `abstract` class, every method is implemented. I think I have put the `@JsonIgnore` everywhere I can that is applicable.

I still get that exception and do not know how to solve it.

I have a feeling that there is something in the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation that might fix this but the examples and javadoc are not written for someone that does not already know when or how to use the annotation.

#### What am I missing?

Comment: Make `id` [`transient`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/910374/2970947)?

Comment: there is no actual `id` member variable, it is just a `method` to return something that is considered the `id` for another part of the program. `ID<String>` in some cases and `ID<Integer>` in others. I changed the example to show this case.

Comment: Is `V`, in reality, a type variable that `extends Identifiable<Something>`? And that is bound to `User` at some call site? The `TypeReference` can't actually capture `User` in that case. The type token hack captures the actual type in the source code, which in this case would be `V`, from which it would extract any generic bounds, and use that to the best of its abilities. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283606/does-jackson-typereference-work-when-extended) and similar for Gson [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773850/gson-typetoken-with-dynamic-arraylist-item-type)

Comment: in this case `V` is `User`, this is a working version that had `User` everywhere that `V`is now. I generified it to try and reused it because I need about a dozen classes that do the exact same thing except for the types.

Comment: If I use `new TypeReference<Set<User>>` (and some other basic assumptions), your sample parses the JSON fine. If `V` is a type variable (a method's generic type variable or a class'), it won't and I get the exception you described (for the reasons I described in my previous comments). As always, that [mcve] is critical :)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I have solved it and will post the solution when I get a chance tomorrow. I got rid of the `Identifiable<T>` interface completely and have what I think is a much better design. Avoiding inheritance is most always the better way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to bind your JSON to an object of type `Identifiable` instead of an object of type `User`, it doesn't work because `Identifiable` is an interface. The problem isn't in the annotations it's where you are doing the binding.