# TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() { }

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jackson

Since few days ago I started to work on a webservice project. This project is using **Jackson** to marshalling and unmarshalling **JSON objects**. So my question is:

Why always I have to put the `{}` when I am creating an instance of `TypeReference`? I know the constructor is `protected`, but why is `protected`? I think that it's like a hack to make visible the constructor creating an implementation of the constructor since `TypeReference` is `abstract` and you can do it. But what is the point of this?

```
String jsonString = "{\" firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Chen\"}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// properties will store name and value pairs read from jsonString
Map<String, String> properties = objectMapper.readvalue(
    jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>()
        { //
        });
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283606/does-jackson-typereference-work-when-extended

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## TL;DR

Via subclassing it is possible for `TypeReference` to extract the *actual* generic type parameter. E.g:

```
TypeReference<String> ref = new TypeReference<String>(){};
System.out.println(ref.getType());
```

Prints:

```
class java.lang.String
```

This can be useful when you can't use normal classes. E.g when this doesn't work:

```
// doesn't work
Type type = ArrayList<String>.class;
```

You still can get that class by using a `TypeReference`:

```
// will yield Class<ArrayList<String>>>
Type type = new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
```

---

## Detailed

When looking at the [source code of `TypeReference` (using Jackson 2.8.5)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/2.5/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java) you can see that the constructor body contains the following lines:

```
Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
if (superClass instanceof Class<?>) { // sanity check, should never happen
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
}
_type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

The interesting lines are the first and last. Let's take a closer look at the first line:

```
Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

For example when you're creating a subclass, by using an anonymous class:

```
TypeReference<SomeStype> ref = new TypeReference<SomeType>(){};
```

Then `getClass` returns the current `Class` object (an anonymous class), and `getGenericSuperclass()` will return the `Class` object from the `class` the current implementation extends from, in our case, `superClass` will equal `Class<TypeReference<?>>`.

Now when looking at the last line from the constructor body:

```
_type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

As we know that the `superClass` is the `Class` object for `TypeReference<?>` we know that it has a generic parameter. Hence the cast to `ParameterizedType`. This specified `Type` has the method `getActualyTypeArguments()` which returns an array of all generic parameters specified by that class. In our case it's just 1. So `[0]` will yield the first element. In the example we will get the actually specified type parameter `SomeType`.